# Our client doesn't like pop-ups, what should we do?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Besides showing and hiding a `<div>`, are there any better solutions or replacements to a javascript pop-up windows? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If by "pop-up" you mean opening a new window, you can avoid that in many cases. Look into [modal-dialog boxes](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal), like those used by the jQueryUI framework.

Comment: This article http://www.useit.com/alertbox/application-design.html explains why they work well.

Comment: These modal dialogs work well for some situations, but sometimes you're better served by reworking your UI design to not need them.

Answer (score 6):

First of all; **nobody** likes pop-ups.

The best solution is to modify the interface in such a way that the pop-up in question no longer is necessary. If this cannot be done, there are design issues afoot.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the context: why, what, where, where to, how much (content)

Do you want to:

- help the user with two lines of useful text before he submits a form ("No underscore in ** field, only letters and numbers" - SO is a nice example for that - great, a [styled tooltip](http://webdesignledger.com/resources/11-excellent-solutions-for-creating-tooltips) should do the job with huge bonus points for ARIA and/or unobstrusive JS).
- go fullscreen (I don't and nobody want it anymore: too much abuse in the past)

You can check the left navigation of Amazon.com with and without JS: unobstrusive and well-styled!

No new window, no div? Then you're left with ul, fieldset, object, animated gifs, etc OK no more kidding. Maybe tabs as in www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/

Answer (score 0):

Popups are evil, avoid them if possible.

To replace this, you can try [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), it's pretty cool.